# I get ModuleNotFound Error when importing OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, pip, package

I started learning OpenCV in python and installed it successfully using PyCharm terminal but when I try to import it it gives error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ComputerVision3.7\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I have no idea what's wrong when I try to install it again or uninstall then install it still gives this error even though the terminal says that the package is installed.

```
PS E:\ComputerVision3.7> pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.8.0.74-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (38.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.0 in c:\users\wasif\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.21.6)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.8.0.74
```

Someone please help me. I am desperate learner.

Comment: your pycharm project most likely uses a virtual environment. Try to install through pycharm. Go to `File`->`Settings`. In the settings, select `Project`->`Python Interpreter` and hit the little `+` button and install opencv through that menu

Comment: Thank you so much. I checked there and it didn't contain OpenCV so I am installing it now and hopefully it should work

Comment: py -m pip install opencv-contrib-python Are you using VSC?

Comment: py -m pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.8.0.74